# programmatically scroll instagram followers window using javascript

Tags: javascript, instagram

I'm trying to scroll the followers/following div programmatically on instagram. I thought it would be the same or similar to the standard way of scrolling using javascript.

What I have tried so far:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("_4gt3b");
x.scrollTop += 100;
```

I've also tried:

```
x.scrollBy(0,100);
```

The followers window does not scroll. The scrollTop variable returns Nan, and the scrollBy function returns x.scrollBy is not a function(…). Any guidance to scroll the followers/following window is greatly appreciated.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a nodeList, so you need to access the element(s) in it using a zero-based index.

Comment: @Cbroe, perfect thank you x[0].scrollTop += 100 does what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cbroe's comment above in my question pointed me in the right direction, the following does what I need.

```
x[0].scrollTop += 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this? 
x[ 0 ].scrollTop += 100

Good luck!